# How understandable is "sans" as the opposite of with?

Tags: word-usage

I use on occasion *sans* for *without*. It has the advantage to consist of the same number of letters (great for nice code formatting). Also, writing *without* is 75% longer and I don't like it.

Of course there's *w/* as an abbreviation but partly I wish to use full words (albeit short ones) and partly, consider the below.

> Oh, so clever: with/sans $$$
>   Plain stupid: with/w/o $$$

My fear's that people in general don't understand the context of *sans* and/or that they find my text unnatural, though.

Example from coding world.

```
public enum Equipment
{
  None,
  With,
  Sans,
  Full
}
```

Comment: Are you confusing *w/* with *w/o*? They're abbreviations for *with* and *without*, respectively.

Comment: Yeah, without is w/o... Regardless... I'm not certain that I really understand your examples. I'm not sure what with/sans money has to do with being clever.

Comment: @DanGetz Corrected. Not confusing. Misspelling. Thanks!

Comment: Given that ***sans*** is *not* an English word, not *every* native speaker will understand it. Particularly since your surrounding text (as above) is likely to be littered with ungrammatical and non-idiomatic usages, which will increase the chances that people will simply give up rather than make the effort to understand what you *might* mean. It may just come across as inappropriately pretentious anyway.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, if Shakespeare used it, I tend to consider it a part of the English language by now?

Comment: @Catija The cleverness is not about money but using words of the same length (c.f. from/till, his/her). We programmers like aligned code. And the plain stupid part is the slashes - it's just not saying *with-or-sans* to be but rather *with-or-w-or-o*, which has no sense.

Comment: @Stephie: The concept of "an English word" is slippery (and subjective), but I bet if you asked 100 native Anglophones what ***sans*** meant, half of them wouldn't have a clue. And nearly all the rest would mention that it was a *French* word, while giving you the definition.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: same problem in many other languages... I'm not going to argue and would probably use *without* to be safe. But if Konrad *wants* a four-letter-word, it's not *wrong*.

Comment: @Stephie: Right and wrong are also subjective concepts in this context. I speak French reasonably fluently, and I use ***sans*** from time to time myself in English (always *facetiously*). But I certainly wouldn't use it in the context of code documentation where I don't even *know* who might be reading my text in years to come. I can just imagine all the new punk kids in the coding room sniggering about that pretentious old prat who wrote all those dorky comments in now-obsolete code they're having to rewrite.

Comment: If we're looking for a code solution, then 1 means with, and 0 means without.  Lines up perfectly, uses a minimum of space, all kinds of support for both in DBMS's.  You could also use Y and N for yes and no.  Both standard conventions for having something or not having it.

Comment: I *think* your use of *fear's* in your last paragraph is not idiomatic/grammatical. Perhaps @snailboat or StoneyB could give a concise reason why.

Comment: @Stephie Many English words that Shakespeare used are not in use today.

Comment: @BobRodes You're incorrectly assuming a binary state. Please see the example in the question. Also, it's rather not recommended to use integers for such because it creates [magic numbers]() and calls for documentation (and modern code omits comments as evil, at least in my field).

Comment: @GoDucks Yeah, it looked a bit weird. Check out the edit to see if it appears more intuitive now. I haven't changed the weird part on purpose to see if it's the sentence structure and word ordering that makes it look suspicious. If you still feel that it's unnatural, you've got my blessing to edit.

Comment: @GoDucks I state that you're wrong on your claim about Shakespeare's vocabulary. I dare you to give an example! I'll be able to contradict your example by a counter-example where the word's been used pretty recently. No exceptions! (And if you think that I'm being wrong, consider where I can get those examples of recent usage of such a word... See it?)   :)

Comment: @KonradViltersten Oops.  I didn't see your enum, sorry.  Anyway, my suggestion was really to dig further into your requirements.  I wouldn't presume to come up with an alternative solution to yours with so little knowledge of your problem domain.  I prefer self-documenting code as well (now that storage is dirt cheap), and if you find that your enum is self-explanatory within the context of the domain then by all means use it.  Personally, I'd use without from what I can see.  A goal of having all enum values be the same length conflicts with the goal of self-documenting code to some extent...

Comment: ...because at some point you have to document the abbreviations that you have to make.  If it isn't a goal for all enums, then maybe it doesn't need to be one for this one.  Anyway, that's my reasoning for using without; the word conveys the meaning more clearly when devoid of other context.

Comment: What's the use case for your enum? Those four members don't obviously form a coherent category.

Comment: Sans is valid in a poetic or literary sense but for technical or general use it would be inappropriate.

Comment: As a programmer, my advice when naming variables, types, etc. is to just use the word.  The enum might be slightly less pretty using Without instead of Sans but everyone will know what it means.

Comment: @BobRodes Oh, poo... You're so right! I didn't realize that picking words *outside the **most** intuitive scope* will unavoidably lead to lower self-explanatory quality. And that defeats the purpose. Du'h! Thanks for that remark, mate, and I stand corrected! As a note I can tell you that I used *C_UD* once - an awesome idea **if** you know that it's *CRUD sans Retrieve*, i.e. only writers, no readers. That was a mistake, hehe. Making mistakes is kind of my superpower, hahaha.

Comment: @ssav Agreed. See my comment above to BobRodes.

Comment: @200_success The (master) carrier had a slot for a piece of equipment **and** it had a connector for a (slave) carrier (with its own slot for equipment but no connector to another sub-slave). The states are: *none*: system unequipped (because neither master nor slave is), *with*: system equipped if it's with the slave (because only the slave is equipped), *sans*: system equipped even without slave (because master is equipped), *full*: system equipped both on master and on slave. As in: *00*, *01*, *10*, *11*.

Comment: *cf.* http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/48748/is-sans-a-drop-in-replacement-for-without

Comment: I have a hard time with your terminology, even after seeing the explanation. For clarity, I suggest 1) `BARE` or `UNEQUIPPED`; 2) `SLAVE_ONLY`, 3) `MASTER_ONLY`, and 4) `BOTH` or `FULLY_EQUIPPED`. Having terms that happen to be the same length makes code look neat when it happens to work out, but sometimes it just doesn't work out.

Comment: @200_success Yes, I'm not arguing the case. After the comment by BobRodes I realized that it was deteriorating the readability. Choosing the right taxonomy in this case turned out to be more challenging than writing the program, hehe. I find that refreshing.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The *Oxford English Dictionary* (OED online), gives the [Frequency Band](http://public.oed.com/how-to-use-the-oed/key-to-frequency/) of 5 for **sans**. Such words comprise 4% of the entries in OED.

> This word belongs in Frequency Band 5. Band 5 contains words which occur between 1 and 10 times per million words in typical modern English usage. These tend to be restricted to literate vocabulary associated with educated discourse, although such words may still be familiar within the context of that discourse.

In addition, the *OED* labels *sans* as *Archaic*, including as part of its definition "chiefly with reminiscence of Shakespeare." It also says it is used in jocular nonce words.

The frequency band for **without** is Band 7:

> Band 7 contains words which occur between 100 and 1000 times per million words in typical modern English usage. This includes the main semantic words which form the substance of ordinary, everyday speech and writing...

Comment: Oh, I just learn about frequency bands. That's a cool application of algorithmic scale. And the comparison between those two words is spot-on. Very well formulated answer (and it make it easier for me to pick which one to accept - I was torn before).

Comment: "Jocular" is a good word for what I was trying to convey.

Comment: I hear it more since I moved to Canada than I did in the US, for obvious reasons.

Comment: @Konrad Be warned that use of 'sans' in a context which is neither archaic nor jocular is likely to be perceived as pretentious (in BrEng at least).

Answer (score 5):

*Sans* is of course the French word for without.  We use the word interchangeably with without, but there's a certain sense of insouciance about it that probably wouldn't seem appropriate in the context you appear to be describing.  It wouldn't typically be used in entirely serious prose.

[Here](http://grammarist.com/usage/sans/) is a nice little explanation of usage in English, with some examples that do a good job of conveying what I'm trying to say.

Comment: Who uses the word interchangeablly with *without*?

Comment: Perhaps "to mean the same thing as" is a better characterization than "interchangeably with".

Comment: `Sans is of course the French word for without` "of course"? That's not immediately obvious to anyone. Also, it might be helpful to put "without" in quotes.

Comment: @Azor-Ahai It's obvious to me, and I would think it's obvious to the OP.  But feel free to disagree.

Comment: Sorry, "anyone" wasn't the right word. I meant to say "everyone."

Answer (score 4):

*[sans](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sans)* is a perfectly fine English word with French "heritage".  Technically you can absolutely use it instead of *without*.

My gut feeling is that *sans* is in a somewhat higher register than a more "everyday" *without*, and it may not be in the (active) vocabulary of every reader (you know your audience better than we do), but I see no compelling reason to abstain from it. Whether its use is particularly "clever" is certainly a matter of taste. If you enjoy the word / length / whatever, use it.

Comment: @bobrodes I can't decide which one to accept... Both replies are clear, correct, informative and spot-on...

Comment: @KonradViltersten perhaps the examples in the article I linked will give some idea of when I might use it, for whatever it's worth.

Comment: Why is this downvoted? It's a good reply... I even voted it up so there's at least two downs... People are weird...

Comment: Nevermind, I think I know why... You got into a discussion with someone who felt that it was important to click you a lesson. As I said, people...

Answer (score 3):

My guess:  Far more English speakers know immediately what "with", "without", and even "w/o" mean, than know what "*avec*" and "*sans*" mean.

This is because "with" and "without" are English words, whereas "*avec*" and "*sans*" are French words.

If you want to be sure that your code and comments (that are otherwise written in English) are understood, you should use "without" or "w/o", not "sans".  (Unfortunately, "w/o" does not work in code.)

If you want your comments to line up, manually add space(s) to make them line up.  (Many IDE pretty printers respect how you space your comments, even if they mess up how you space the rest of your code.)

Comment: I see you r point. I'll add a little example in my question to show what **also** it might be useful for. For some reason, when people hear *programming* they tend to interpret it as *comments* or *documentation*. I almost never write comments. It's a very bad habit hiding even more bad issues. At least in my experience.